# MS SQL Server Management Studio - open multiple tables, views for design

Tags: sql-server

While working on a database design, I have to open same set of 3 views and 2 tables every day. This can be done by RMB - Design or RMB - Select Top 200 Rows

Being lazy, I wonder if I can store a "work Environment" that opens up several Windows with one click, then. Perfect would be to remember the layout too (split window)

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1602/sql-server-management-studio-customized-startup-options/

Comment: Althought this isn't really the right place for questions like this...